# React Native: How to debug release build?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have built an app with React Native that works perfectly find in debug mode, but when running the release build it fails when navigating to a scene.

The Xcode console shows a cryptic error message (probably because of minification). I have no idea how to get more out of this error? Is there any way to get more information by bundling differently or looking somewhere else?

```
[tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

This error is located at:
in r
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
in t
in RCTView
in n
in t
in n
in u
in e
in t
in t
in n
in e
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in t
in inject-t-with-app-user
in RCTView
in t
in RCTView
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Firebase Crashlytics with upload dSYMs https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports

Also you can use fastlane for easily https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_symbols_to_crashlytics/